# Invite email contacts - No one received the invitation

Tags: facebook, contacts, invitation

I have a Facebook business page. Recently, I attempted to take advantage of the "build audience" tool. It allows you to upload a .cvs, .txt, or .xml file of email addresses to send an invitation to "like" a Facebook page. I uploaded approximately 5,000 emails. The whole process went smoothly, no errors, I was able to preview the message and hit send without incident. As a control, myself and several other co-workers were included in the list to make sure the invitations went out; not one of us received an invitation. Further, we received no "likes" from the invitation, which leaves me to believe no one received it.

Any ideas on what may have gone wrong?

Should I try again?

I don't want to bombard people with invitations.

Comment: did you check your spam box?

Comment: Yes, of course. No one received it from our company. Plus, I think think the odds of receiving no response from 5,000 people is low. It makes me think the invite was never received (spam filter or no).

Comment: Have you tried sending the emails again? Try with a sample size of 3 to 5 emails. The load of 5,000 might have been too much *even though* Facebook says that the load should be ok.

Comment: I have also tried using this feature with as little as 7 email addresses and it did not work. I tried again with less and it did not work.